# Save all the records by one click jsf hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jsf-2.2, java-ee-7

I'm using JavaEE, JSF 2.2 and hibernate 4.3.1.

Normally when saving the selected row, I just need to save it this way:

```
 <ui:repeat value="#{casesBean.editableNotes}"  var="notes" varStatus="status">
  <table style="width:100%" class="tables">
    <tr>
       <th>
          <h:outputText value="Officer :  "/>
       </th>
       <th>
          <h:inputText value="#{notes.creator}"/> 
      </th>
   </table>
</ui:repeat>

<p:commandButton value="Update" action="#{casesBean.save(notes)}">
```

Bean:

```
public void save(Notes notes){
    this.currentNote = notes;
    Notes notes = new Notes(currentNote.creator.... all the items here);
    helper.updateNote(notes);
}
```

Helper:

```
public void updateNote(Notes notes) {
    Transaction transaction = null;
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.update(notes);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (transaction != null) {
            transaction.rollback();
        }
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

But this way only can save the selected row/record which means that only one record is saved. How to save all the records in the DataModel editableNotes at the same time, just by clicking on the button?